# "timestamp":"2023-01-22T11:03:24.467+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/api/api/acco/treansfer/1/2/20000"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, request-mapping

my controller class is

```
package com.SystemFinal.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.SystemFinal.entity.Account;
import com.SystemFinal.repository.AccountRepository;
import com.SystemFinal.service.AccountService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/acco")

    @RequestMapping(value = "treansfer{acctID}/{destAcctID}/{amount}",method=RequestMethod.PUT, produces= {MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},consumes= {MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, headers ="Accept=Application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> transferAmount(@PathVariable int acctID, @PathVariable int destAcctID, @PathVariable int amount){
        try {
            accountRepository.saveBalanceById(acctID,destAcctID, amount);
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
    
}
```

**My entity class is

```
package com.SystemFinal.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="acco")
public class Account implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
private int id;
    @Column(name="account_number")
private int account_number;
    @Column(name= "balance")
private int balance;
    @Column(name="p_status")
private String p_status;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getAccount_number() {
    return account_number;
}
public void setAccount_number(int account_number) {
    this.account_number = account_number;
}
public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
public void setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
public String getP_status() {
    return p_status;
}
public void setP_status(String p_status) {
    this.p_status = p_status;
}


}
```

**repository class**

```
package com.SystemFinal.repository;

import java.lang.annotation.Repeatable;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.SystemFinal.entity.Account;
@Repository("AccountRepository")
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Integer>,JpaRepository<Account, Integer>{
    @Query(value="select balance from acco where id=?1",nativeQuery = true)
    public int getBalanceById(int acc);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query(value="update acco set balance=balance+?3 where id=?1,set balance=balance-?3 where id=?2",nativeQuery = true)
    public void saveBalanceById(int id,int raccId ,int amount);
    @Transactional
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query(value="update acco set balance=balance-?2 where id=?1",nativeQuery = true)
    public void withdrawById(int id,int balance);
}
```

**service class**

```
package com.SystemFinal.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.SystemFinal.entity.Account;
@Service
public interface AccountService {
    public Iterable<Account> findAllAccount();
    public Account findById(int id);
    public void createAccount(Account acc);
    public void updateAccount(Account acc);
    public void deleteAccount(int id);
}
```

**service implementing class**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.SystemFinal.entity.Account;
import com.SystemFinal.repository.AccountRepository;
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService{

    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepository;
    @Override
    public Iterable<Account> findAllAccount() {
        return accountRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Account findById(int id) {
        return accountRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public void createAccount(Account acc) {
        accountRepository.save(acc);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void updateAccount(Account acc) {
        accountRepository.save(acc);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAccount(int id) {
        accountRepository.deleteById(id);
        
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8083
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bankdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
server.servlet.context-path=/api
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.SystemFinal</groupId>
    <artifactId>SystemFinal</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SystemFinal</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have a table with the name acco and I try to update one of its columns with the query below

```
@Transactional
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query(value="update acco set balance=balance+?3 where id=?1,set balance=balance-?3 where id=?2",nativeQuery = true)
    public void saveBalanceById(int id,int raccId ,int amount);
```

when I test it says

> "timestamp":"2023-01-22T11:03:24.467+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not
> Found","path":"/api/api/acco/treansfer/1/2/20000 "

I am new to spring boot please help me .

Comment: remove one of the `/api` from the url: `/api/api/acco/treansfer/1/2/20000`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether or not you have called a right mapping
Mapping is: `api/acco/treansfer{acctID}/{destAcctID}/{amount}`

And the url is:

```
http://localhost:8083/api/acco/treansfer{acctID}/{destAcctID}/{amount}
```